# React-native Invoke API from one common handler class

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a common function which uses FETCH to get data from external web service. this function will be invoked and parsed in multiple screens under componentDidMount(). instead of repeating the same code at multiple places, I put below under a common class, but unfortunately, data is not returned to those screens.

Common Function

```
export function convertValue(fromVal, toVal) {
var requestObj = {};
let apiEndpoint = '<target endpoint>'
return  fetch(apiEndpoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            return responseJson;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        });}
```

Sample call below, and no pop-up when screen loaded.

```
componentDidMount () {
AsyncStorage.getItem('user_default').then((value) => {
    this.setState({userDefault: value});
}).then((value) => {
    var sample = convertValue('A', 'B');
    Alert.alert(
                                'Success',
                                JSON.stringify(sample),
                                [
                                  {text: 'OK',
                                    onPress: () => {
                                      console.log('.');
                                    }}
                                ]
                              )
});}
```

Comment: convertValue is returning a Promise, not your JSON result.

Answer (score 0):

```
        componentDidMount () { 
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user_default').then((value) => { 
    this.setState({userDefault: value}); 
      convertValue('A', 'B').then((json)=>{
alert(json)
})
})}
```

This might work for you. The problem was improper chaining of asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 0):

Nick is right, found the right way -

```
convertValue('A', 'B')
                    .then((responseJson) => {
                        this.setState({returnedValue: responseJson.convertedValue});
                    });
```